# How do I format observed data for use in Bayesian networks in pymc3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I'm struggling to understand how observed data works in pymc3. From the information I've found so far, [these](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1079) [two](https://gist.github.com/tbsexton/1349864212b25cce91dbe5e336d794b4) examples have been the most helpful for getting me as far as I have, but I can't get my model to work.

As an example of what I'm trying to do, say I have records from customers at a restaurant, recording the temperature of the day on a categorical rating scale out of 5, and whether or not they ordered a main meal, a side, or a beverage.  I've set up some mock data like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from theano import shared

no_of_root_categories = 5
no_of_samples = 1000
hot_day = np.random.randint(no_of_root_categories, size=no_of_samples)
option_labels = ["Main", "Side", "Beverage"]
meal_options = np.random.randint(2, size=(len(option_labels), no_of_samples))
```

I want to model it as a simple Bayesian network, like so:

[image: Bayesian network model]

where the shaded nodes are observed.

This is what I've got:

```
with pm.Model() as crashing_model:
    shape = (no_of_samples, no_of_root_categories)
    alpha = (1 / no_of_root_categories) * np.ones(shape)
    root_prior = pm.Dirichlet("Temperature Rating Prior", alpha, shape=shape)
    root = pm.Categorical('Temperature Rating', p=root_p, shape=no_of_samples, observed=hot_day)

    for item, label in enumerate(option_labels):
        node_data = meal_options[item, :]
        theano_probs = shared(np.array(node_probs))
        node_prior = pm.Beta(f"{label} Prior",
                             mu=root,
                             sigma=root,
                             shape=no_of_samples,
                             testval=np.random.randint(1, size=no_of_samples))
        pm.Binomial(label, p=node_prior, n=no_of_samples, observed=node_data)
```

which works, but when I try

```
with crashing_model:
    trace = pm.sample(1000, random_seed=0)
```

Python exits with a 'Bad initial energy' error.

I can create a model which seems to work without the latent variables

```
with pm.Model() as working_model: # seems to work
    root_values = [np.where(hot_day == i)[0].tolist() for i in range(no_of_root_categories)]
    root_p = [len(i) / 1000 for i in root_values]
    root = pm.Categorical('Temperature Rating', p=root_p)

    shared_proportions = shared(np.array([len(hot_day[i]) for i in root_values]))
    for item, label in enumerate(option_labels):
        node_probs = [sum([meal_options[item, idx] for idx in category]) / len(category) for category in root_values]
        theano_probs = shared(np.array(node_probs))
        pm.Binomial(label, p=theano_probs[root], n=shared_proportions[root])
```

but I'm not sure how to translate what I've done there to work with the latent variables. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the [pymc3 discourse](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/observed-data-in-bayesian-networks/5513/3) I got it working. I'd somehow gotten the idea that I needed to make sure all the shapes were the same, but I didn't need to specify them at all. Code below for anyone else who has trouble.

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    shape = (no_of_samples, no_of_root_categories)
    alpha = np.ones(no_of_root_categories)
    root_prior = pm.Dirichlet("Temperature Rating Prior", alpha)
    root = pm.Categorical('Temperature Rating', p=root_p, observed=hot_day)

    for item, label in enumerate(option_labels):
        node_data = meal_options[item, :]
        theano_alpha_probs = shared(np.ones(no_of_root_categories))
        theano_beta_probs = shared(np.ones(no_of_root_categories))
        node_prior = pm.Beta(f"{label} Prior",
                             alpha=theano_alpha_probs[root],
                             beta=theano_beta_probs[root],
                             testval=0.5)
        pm.Bernoulli(label, p=node_prior, observed=node_data)
```